# Why am I getting a broken token response?

Tags: javascript, post, axios, oauth, discord

I am creating a login system using discord oauth.

During development, I succeeded in logging in from oauth and getting a code, but I ran into a problem where I couldn't get a token afterwards.

I tried with the following code

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('client_id', client_id);
params.append('client_secret', client_secret);
params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
params.append('code', code);
params.append('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost/callback');

const token = await axios.post('https://discord.com/api/v10/oauth2/token', params);
console.log(token.data);
```

and got the following output

```
V�@6���\���
u���%�%O~��F&��J�|_'*��d2ý��(��Q�2�ۊK�K1�
���l�6��'�W��@����Qtd�|�      M�>.�X
```

same request in hoppscotch
[image: same request in hoppscotch]

Things I've tried:

1. `Content-Type: application/json` -> discord api didn't allow it
2. `responseEncoding: 'utf8'` option -> same output

How can I get unbroken output?

Axios: 1.2.0

Comment: Have you tried `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`?

Comment: Using URLSearchParams seems to send the request with those header. And my original code was using data and its headers without URLSearchParams.

discord oauth token api didn't work without that header